# No repeat in itertools.combinations based on nested sequence element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

```
source=[['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['d', 2], ['e', 2], ['f',3]]
target=[list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(source,3)]
for i in target: print(i)

[['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['d', 2]]
[['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['e', 2]]
[['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['f', 3]]
[['a', 1], ['d', 2], ['e', 2]]
[['a', 1], ['d', 2], ['f', 3]]
[['a', 1], ['e', 2], ['f', 3]]
[['b', 1], ['d', 2], ['e', 2]]
[['b', 1], ['d', 2], ['f', 3]]
[['b', 1], ['e', 2], ['f', 3]]
[['d', 2], ['e', 2], ['f', 3]]
```

Can I have itertools.combinations not repeat by nested sequence element?  In this case, element [1] of each nested sequence to produce:

```
[['a', 1], ['d', 2], ['f', 3]]
[['a', 1], ['e', 2], ['f', 3]]
[['b', 1], ['d', 2], ['f', 3]]
[['b', 1], ['e', 2], ['f', 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Split out your input list into separate groups instead and produce their product. You could use `itertools.groupby()` if your input is sorted by the second parameter:

```
from itertools import groupby, product
from operator import itemgetter

source = [['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['d', 2], ['e', 2], ['f', 3]]
grouped = (list(group) for key, group in groupby(source, key=itemgetter(1)))
for combo in product(*grouped):
    print(list(combo))
```

If you input is not sorted by the second parameter, you'd group them by using a dictionary:

```
source = [['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['d', 2], ['e', 2], ['f', 3]]
groups = {}
for item in source:
    groups.setdefault(item[1], []).append(item)
grouped = [group for key, group in sorted(groups.items())]
```

where I assume you wanted to sort on that same second value to inform the final output order.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a generator that filters the results:

```
import itertools

def my_combinations(*args, **kw):
    for result in itertools.combinations(*args, **kw):
        _,l = zip(*result)
        if len(l) == len(set(l)):
            yield result

source=[['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['d', 2], ['e', 2], ['f',3]]
target=[list(x) for x in my_combinations(source,3)]
for i in target: print(i)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you filter out the majority of elements, and the amount of work to be done increases quadratically when elements are added to the input. My approach groups in O(N) time before producing only the actual combinations needed.